# How gevent socketio writing to client is a blocking call

Tags: python, socket.io, gevent, gevent-socketio

I know reading from client is blocking call as we have to wait for the input from the user.
But, how writing to the client is a blocking call? 
And also if i send two client messages, lets say msg1 and msg2 using gevent socketio put_client_msg module, in what order will they reach the client?

Thanks,
Ram.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [examples](https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio/tree/master/examples)? I don't think you're meant to use `put_client_msg`. Either use `socket.send_packet` or if in the namespace, `self.emit`. I also don't think anything in the communication should actually block.

Comment: I figured that socket connection uses TCP protocol and messages to the client are sent in the same order.